# Simplify the given expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I been stuck on this for half an hour now and I need some help, I need to simplify the expression: $$\left[\left(\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{\left(1+a^{2}\right)^{-1}}\right) - \left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{a^{-1}}\right)\right] \cdot\frac{a^{-3}}{1-a^{-2}}$$

Comment: i can not read this

Comment: It's not just about saying that you've done some efforts to solve to problem,it's about to prove it.

Comment: @Nameless I cant prove because I couldn't came up with a sensible answer yet

Comment: You can atleast show us where you got stuck. Anyways I have posted an answer.

Comment: There's no need to come up with a sensible answer,it's just about to share your thoughts on the problem,to tell what are the crucial points which you find hard to tackle and ,if possible, to tell what you think the answer would be etc...so that you can learn the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\left[\left(\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{\left(1+a^{2}\right)^{-1}}\right) - \left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{a^{-1}}\right)\right] \cdot\frac{a^{-3}}{1-a^{-2}} &= \left[\sqrt{2}a\left(1+a^2\right)-2\sqrt{2}a\right]\frac{1}{a^3\left(1-a^{-2}\right)} \\
&= \frac{\left[\sqrt{2}\color{red}{\cancel a}\left(1+a^2\right)-2\sqrt{2}\color{red}{\cancel a}\right]}{\color{red}{\cancel a}\left(a^2-1\right)} \\
&= \frac{\left[\sqrt{2}\left(1+a^2\right)-2\sqrt{2}\right]}{\left(a^2-1\right)} \\ &= \frac{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}a^2}{\left(a^2-1\right)} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}\color{red}{\cancel {\left(a^2-1\right)}}}{\color{red}{\cancel {\left(a^2-1\right)}}} \\
&= \sqrt{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Very elaborate answer

Answer (score 1):

$$(a\sqrt{2}(1+a^2)-2\sqrt{2}a)\frac{1}{(a^2-1)a} =\frac{\sqrt{2}(a^2-1)}{(a^2-1)}=\sqrt{2}$$

**EDIT** $\frac{a^{-3}}{(1-a^{-2})}=\frac{\frac{1}{a^3}}{(1-\frac{1}{a^2})}=\frac{a^2}{a^3(a^2-1)}=\frac{1}{a(a^2-1)}$

Comment: Can you include the omitted algorithm because I cant understand how you got 1/(a^2-1)a as the second multiplier.